# Data retrieved from graphql useQuery not displaying in child component but is available in the state and props

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am experiencing an issue which may simply be due to my limited understanding of graphql and react rendering methods.  That being said, I hope someone can assist.

I have a simple app with a USERS and USER component.

I retrieve data in the USERS app using the Apollo useQuery hook. I then pass the data down to the USER component via both directly adding it as props and useState.
When I access the Chrome and Apollo Developer tools, I can see the props and state data is correct.
But the Textfield in the USER component displays empty data.
The Textfield in the USERS component is being displayed just fine.

[image]

USERS.js

```js
export default function Users() {
  const [UserInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(USER_DATA);
  const { register, watch, handleSubmit, control, reset, errors } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    // if (data) {
    //   const { id, name, username } = data.users.data[0];
    //   setUserInfo({ id, name, username });
    // }

    if (loading === false && data) {
      setUserInfo(data.users.data[0]);
    }
  }, [loading, data]);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hi there</h1>
      {console.log(data)}
      {/* User component */}

      <div style={{ border: "10px solid green", padding: "5px" }}>
        <h3>From the USERS Component</h3>
        <Controller
          as={TextField}
          variant="outlined"
          required
          fullWidth
          id="firstName"
          label="First Name"
          name="firstName"
          autoComplete="fname"
          control={control}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          defaultValue={data.users.data[0].name}
          margin="dense"
        />
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          label="First Name"
          variant="outlined"
          margin="dense"
          value={UserInfo.name}
        />
        <div style={{ border: "10px solid red", padding: "5px" }}>
          <User
            id={data.users.data[0].id}
            UserInfo={UserInfo}
            name={data.users.data[0].name}
            username={data.users.data[0].username}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

User.js

```js
export default function User({id, UserInfo, name, username}) {
  const { register, watch, handleSubmit, control, reset, errors } = useForm();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>From the User Component</h3>
      <TextField
        id="standard-required"
        fullWidth
        label="Required"
        value={UserInfo.name}
        variant="outlined"
        margin="dense"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

CODESANDBOX available here: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-river-1zdd2?file=/src/User.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually had to add a conditional statement in the USERS component to make it work.  Whether it is the best solution is up for debate.  If there are better solutions, please let me know.

Updated code:

USERS.js

```js
export default function Users() {
  const [UserInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(undefined);
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(USER_DATA);
  const { register, watch, handleSubmit, control, reset, errors } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    // if (data) {
    //   const { id, name, username } = data.users.data[0];
    //   setUserInfo({ id, name, username });
    // }

    if (loading === false && data) {
      setUserInfo(data.users.data[0]);
    }
  }, [loading, data]);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hi there</h1>
      {console.log(data)}
      {/* User component */}

      <div style={{ border: "10px solid green", padding: "5px" }}>
        <h3>From the USERS Component</h3>
        <Controller
          as={TextField}
          variant="outlined"
          required
          fullWidth
          id="firstName"
          label="First Name"
          name="firstName"
          autoComplete="fname"
          control={control}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          defaultValue={data.users.data[0].name}
          margin="dense"
        />
        <div style={{ border: "10px solid red", padding: "5px" }}>
          {/* ===== ADDED THE CONDITIONAL BELOW ===== */}
          {UserInfo !== undefined ? (
            <User
              id={data.users.data[0].id}
              UserInfo={UserInfo}
              name={data.users.data[0].name}
              username={data.users.data[0].username}
            />
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

USER.js

```js
export default function User({ id, UserInfo, name, username }) {
  const { register, watch, handleSubmit, control, reset, errors } = useForm();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>From the User Component</h3>
      <TextField
        id="standard-required"
        fullWidth
        label="Required"
        value={UserInfo.name}
        variant="outlined"
        margin="dense"
      />
   
    </div>
  );
}
```